# React + D3: Data over Y AXIS in scatter plot not appear correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm newbie with D3 and I trying to create a Scatterplot graphic. When I try to create the points in the graphics this don't appear correctly.

I've got 9 points to put in the scatterplot but only appears 5. And all of these are not located correctly in their positions. For example, we've got one in (0, 0) and is over the x = 0 correctly but the position in the y axis is not 0 is almost 2.

[image]

The data of all points are:

```
name: GOMEZ IGUAL, ANNA x: 0.00 y: 20.00

name: PARKS, ROBYN LASHAE x: 15.00 y: 20.00

name: CASAS CARRERAS, QUERALT x: 25.00 y: 20.00

name: ABALDE DIAZ, TAMARA x: 15.00 y: 0.00

name: TIRERA, MEIYA x: 15.00 y: 0.00

name: BUCH ROSELL, ROSO x: 0.00 y: 0.00

name: BROWN, JOY ALEXIS x: 15.00 y: 20.00

name: RAMAN, JANA GEORGES R x: 0.00 y: 20.00

name: REISINGEROVA, JULIA x: 15.00 y: 0.00
```

And the code where I draw the points is:

```
setPointsToCanvas(canvas, data, scales){
    console.log("data length: " + data.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        console.log("name: " + data[i].name + " x: " + data[i].value_x + " y: " + data[i].value_y);
    }
    console.log("\n");
    canvas.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 5.5)     //Radius size, could map to another dimension
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return scales.xScale(parseFloat(d.value_x)); })  //x position
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y)); })  //y position
    .style("fill", "#FFC107")
    .on("mouseover", this.tipMouseOver);

}
```

How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

The reason of why are only visible 5 points insted of 9 is due because there are (x, y) repeated and I only see one of them.

But, If we look at the graphic we can see that the points are correctly situated over x axis but not over y axis. For example, let's check the points over x = 0. (0, 0) and (0, 20). We can see two points over the 0 value in the x axis but these points are wrong located over the y Axis, the y value 0 is arond 2 value and th y value 20 is around 21 value in the gaphic.

How is that possible? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit II:**

Here is a codesandbox

[image: Edit twilight-star-xmenq]

**Edit III:**

If I substract 1.50 to the y position then the points are located correctly:

```
.attr("cy", function(d) {
  return scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y) - 1.50);
})
```

[image]

Why I have to do that? What happend? Is there any better option to fix the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you add [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard) to your question? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Ok, please, give me some minutes to do it!!! It will be my first codesandbox :)

Comment: Done it!!! @Ma'mounothman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I debugged your code.

And I found your yAxis and xAxis positions are transformed with wrong values.
Also the domains of xScale and yScale are incremented or decremented unnecessarily.

I pull out some modified code with the comment added.

```
  let xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([
      d3.min(data, d => parseFloat(d.value_x)), // No need +1
      d3.max(data, d => parseFloat(d.value_x))  // Same here
    ])
    .range(xRange);
```

```
  // You don't need y-axis direction transform.
  let y2 = 0;
  // You should match this value with the yRange
  // let yRange = [20, 360 - 20 - 30];
  let y1 = 360 - 20 - 30;
...
  canvas
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + y1 + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
...
  canvas
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 40 + "," + y2 + ")")
    .call(yAxis)
...
```

I think having offset value as constant is a good practice for this kind of work.

Please check this codesandbox.

[image: Edit Data in scatter plot not appear correctly]

Comment: Hi @tatsuya kanemoto!!! Yout developmnt works fine but I don't know why with other data, there are a pair of points which are not correctly located :(I don't understand anything :(

Comment: These two points has the same x value = 3.03 and these points are located over 0 value :(((( I have updated CodeSandBox with the new values.

Comment: The 3.03 is not located over 0. It's in right place. The problem is the xScale's domain depends on min value using `d3.min(...)`. So you need to change to `d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value_x)]).range(xRange)`.

Comment: It works @tatsuya kanemoto!!! Thank you very much for your appreciated help!!!